# std::copy setting pointer to null

Tags: c++, copy, std

I'm working on some code, and I have a point where I grab some amount of binary data, then want to extract some bytes from it.  So, I have the following:

```
unsigned char * payload;
int payload_size;
uint32_t major = 0, minor = 0;
payload = out_resp.get_payload(&payload_size); // Retrieve the data, return a pointer
if(payload_size >= 8) { // Need at least 8 bytes in the payload
    std::copy(payload, payload + 4, &major);
    std::copy(payload + 4, payload + 8, &minor);
}
```

As you can see, the first four bytes from the payload should be placed in `major`, and the next four in `minor`.  However, while going through debugging, I'm noticing that after the first `std::copy`, my variable `payload` is set to `NULL`!

Is this expected behavior for `std::copy`, or is something going wrong?  Should I avoid this by simply creating another pointer, and passing that to `std::copy`?

Comment: I'm running through GDB.  When GDB gets to the second copy line, I `print payload`, and receive: `(gdb) print payload` ; `$4 = (unsigned char *) 0x0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::copy` doesn't work like `memcpy`. Your `std::copy(payload, payload + 4, &major);` will copy:

```
(&major)[0] = payload[0];
(&major)[1] = payload[1];
(&major)[2] = payload[2];
(&major)[3] = payload[3];
```

And that's not what you need. `(&major)[1]` is outside the bounds, so assigning to it causes undefined behavior.

Comment: Well... that makes sense, and changing to memcpy does in fact work.  Thank you!